# How to automatically (by UT) detect missing no-args constructors in REST contracts?

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, spring-boot

I'm working on a SpringBoot application which contains dozens of REST endpoints with dozens of methods. All of them are declared using `@RestController` annotation. Consequently there comes a big number of POJOs that serves as contracts for all these methods. And it often happens that new developers forget to declare no arguments constructors on these classes. So this runs into problems described under this link:
https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/01/why-default-or-no-argument-constructor-java-class.html

And what's worse, this kind of errors are detected after the application is deployed to TEST environment.

So my question is there an easy way to automatically detect missing no-args constructors in Java? Without test suite with `@EnableMvc` annotation? Preferably it would the best to detect such cases for the newly created POJOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be lot of ways,
ex: Sonar with custom rules, IDE inspection plugins or inbuilt code analysis.

But i recommend you to write spring MockMVC tests (very easy to implement), there are lot of articles that you can refer online. 
ex:
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/spring-boot-mockmvc-example/

if Spring can not instantiate any class or (controller) in the code flow, your test will fail. other advantage is you can test your all REST APIs with a good quality test (mock all DAO and try to test only the spring MVC layer).

Answer (score 2):

Only solution known to me is java Reflection you'll have to scan the package then check for the annotation then for the default constructor try out this test class which will print classes without default constructor.

```
public class TestListIni {


    String scaningPackage = "your package name";

    public void startTesting() {

        List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<ClassLoader>();
        classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader());
        classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader());

        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
                new ConfigurationBuilder().setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false), new ResourcesScanner())
                        .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList.toArray(new ClassLoader[0])))
                        .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix(scaningPackage))));

        Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);

        allClasses.forEach(oneClass -> {
            RestController addTotest = oneClass.getAnnotation(RestController.class);
            if (addTotest != null) {
                //check for default constructor
                boolean flag = hasParameterlessPublicConstructor(oneClass);
                if(!flag){
                    sysout("this has no default constructor " oneClass.getName());
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("Scanned and exclued class " + oneClass.getName());
            }
        });


    }

    private boolean hasParameterlessPublicConstructor(Class<?> clazz) {
    for (Constructor<?> constructor : clazz.getConstructors()) {

        if (constructor.getParameterCount() == 0) { 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
}
```

dependency :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write unit testing with mockMvc as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-mock-environment

Moreover, I prefer using a default constructor instead of (no-arg constructor + setter) for deserialization.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a stupid solution, but why not just create an instance by

```
POJOClass pojoClass = new POJOClass();
```

and assert it's not null?

Comment: How can it be null after calling constructor?

Comment: @rkosegi, if no-args constructor is missing, the IDE will tell it or an exception raised in UT, so the developer will of course know there's something wrong.

Comment: Let me ask again, how can it be null? If no-args ctor is missing, then it's compilation error.

Comment: Yes, you are right, 
if no-args is missing, then it's compilation error and UT won't pass.
if no-args is *not* missing, the UT *should* pass, by assert pojoClass is not null.

Comment: UT will not even run as it can't be compiled.